# Is it a gcc -O2 optimization bug (different result from -O1)?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I write a very simple program, it behaves normal without `-O2`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t A[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    float B[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    float C[4] = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int i;

    // convert integer A to float B
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        B[i] = (float)A[i];

    // memory copy from B to C
    uint32_t *src = (uint32_t*)(B);
    uint32_t *dst = (uint32_t*)(C);
    dst[0] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[2] = src[2];
    dst[3] = src[3];

#if 0
    // open this to correct the error
    __asm__("":::"memory");
#endif

    // print C, C should be [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        printf("%f\n", C[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile without `-O2`:

```sh
$ gcc error.c -o error
$ ./error
1.0000
2.0000
3.0000
4.0000
```

It works as expected. But if I added a `-O2`:

```
$ gcc -O2 error.c -o error
$ ./error
-6169930235904.000000
0.000000
-6169804406784.000000
0.000000
```

In addition, if you switch `#if 0` to `#if 1` , it works correctly again. The `asm ("":::"memory")` should be unecessary in the same thread.

Is it a bug of `-O2` optimization ??

Is there any thing I can tell the compiler to care of it ?? I have a function to store xmm register to a (void*) pointer, like:

```c
inline void StoreRegister(void *ptr, const __m128& reg)
{
#if DONT_HAVE_SSE
    const uint32_t *src = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(&reg);
    uint32_t *dst = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(ptr);
    dst[0] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[2] = src[2];
    dst[3] = src[3];
#else
    _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(ptr), _mm_castps_si128(reg));
#endif
}
```

The `dst` is the `C` in the code above, any way to make it correct without modifying the function signature.

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior resulting from strict aliasing violations

Comment: `uint32_t *src = (uint32_t*)(B);
        uint32_t *dst = (uint32_t*)(C);` breaks strict aliasing rules.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you see an "optimization bug" it is very likely undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: Use `std::copy` (C++) or `std::` `memcpy` (C/C++).

Comment: `gcc -Q -v -O2 main.cpp` to verbosely display which optimization flags gcc is using. 
 Note:  not all optimizations under `-O2` have a corresponding individual flag.  And `-O0` disables all optimizations except required ones by the C standard or C++ standard.  (Disabling an optimization because the code has undefined behavior is just a band-aid, and not good programing practice.)

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `float B[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };`  Those literals are integers, not floats.   Suggest: `float B[4] = { 0.0f, 0,0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };`

Comment: the posted code (and compile statements) are in the C language, not the C++ language.  They are very different languages.  Please remove the `c++` tag from the question

Answer (score 11):

No this is not a manifestation of a compiler bug.

Rather the behaviour of your code is *undefined* due to your using the result of the cast `(uint32_t*)(B)` &c. This is a violation of *strict aliasing*.

Compilers - particularly gcc - are becoming more and more aggressive when it comes to treating undefined constructs. They are allowed by the standard to assume that undefined behaviour does not occur, and can remove any branch that contains it.

Comment: Is there any thing I can tell the compiler to care of it ?? I have a function to store xmm register to a (void*) pointer, which is B in my problem.

Comment: @skywind3000 `std::copy` to the rescue!

Comment: or `memcpy`, as this appears to be C code despite the C++ tag.

Comment: better yet [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) if it's available

Comment: You could try the `-fstrict-aliasing` flag (`-fno-strict-aliasing`) ... or use a `union{}` to avoid the undefined behavior

Comment: @technosaurus: If code can benefit from exploiting storage layouts, using dialects that define the behavior (e.g. `-fno-strict-aliasing`) is better than jumping through hoops to abide the limitations of a dialect *that are less suitable for the task*.